# How to log the actual output in apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, logging, lamp

I am doing LAMP development for a mobile platform. However, the client browser does not allow me to view the source code of visited pages. I consider the source code to be of huge importance for debugging, so I would like to configure my web server so every time a user makes a request, in addition to sending the client a response, that response (the actual contents of the returned page) is also stored in a file with a filename I can cross-relate with access_log (maybe ip-timestamp-filename? or maybe a unique ID in an additional column in access_log?).

I've searched quite a bit, but haven't even gotten close to finding what I'm looking for. Has anybody been able to do this?

Comment: Good question, thanks for asking it. Seems like someone I myself will find the need for sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra module for doing this: [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html).

[Here](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/124161) you'll find an short article how to use it.

Comment: So far so good. However, I'm worried that: 1. It puts everything in the error log. This is problematic because. 2. It won't log binary files. I am dynamically generating images and swf data, so I also need binary data. 3. It appears to be truncating my data! Still reading about it so I'll be back in a bit. If you have more ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to load the page with another browser from a regular desktop ? :p

Comment: Because the application requires some crypto stuff which is provided by the carrier, which I can't fake nor remove.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually forgot a much more obvious way of doing this. You can simply do tcpdump on the server and then analyze with Wireshark.

This doesn't work for HTTPS though...

Comment: Try putting stunnel in front of a HTTP webserver and tapping the traffic in between, or use curl as the client